# Silverlight Scheduling Control

Tags: silverlight

Does anyone know of any freely available scheduling control for Silverlight 3? Something that resembles the Day/Week/Month view in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT FREE
Telerik has a decent looking scheduler control.
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Scheduler/FirstLook

I don't work for Telerik - I've been listening to them talking about it for weeks on DNR.  Been using some Telerik Silverlight controls and I've found them to be decent.

Comment: Telerik seems to be the forerunner for Silverlight controls at this time.  I'll be honest and say that their Grid isn't as fast as I'd like to see it, but their other controls are pretty peppy... I'm getting anxious to start diving into their scheduler control for... well.. scheduling in a LOB application that I'm working on.  

Only time will tell as the other vendors (Infragistics, DevExpress, etc.) catch up and show their stuff to the world if Telerik really is on top, or if it is that they were just "First to market."

Answer (score 0):

most promising so far from checking the demos is this one
http://www.palmsoft.com/webscheduler/
its not yet published though :~